# IntelliJ show changed lines not covered by unit tests

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

In my daily work, I intend to write tests for the code that I change.

My workflow usually is like this:

- Find code to change
- Write failing test
- Change code
- Watch test pass

And before commit, I run all tests.

But in reality, I could change any lines unknowingly about our test coverage.

What I do now is usually to see if the CI server will show increasing test coverage. But this is a manual task which I have to do after my commit, and it also may be cluttered by others committing code.

How can IntelliJ help me? I cannot directly find a way to compare test coverage. How can I ensure my changes drive test coverage up?

How do you currently handle this aspect of your code coverage?

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ IDEA includes the [code coverage](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/07/code-coverage/) support since the 6.0 version (Ultimate edition).

Through Run -> Edit Configurations -> Code Coverage you can configure the code coverage you want, then you can issue the "Run tests with coverage" command. You'll have as a result some code coverage data on the project view. When you open a source file you can also see what lines are fully covered, partially covered, or not covered at all.

You might want to customize the Colors & Fonts through File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General modifying the following entries:

- Full line coverage
- Partial line coverage
- Uncovered line

For example I wanted to add more evidency to the coverage, so I configured a different background for those lines.

Once you have some red lines (not covered), you can try to cover them and if you see them becoming green it means you did a good job, and so on!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware that IntelliJ can show coverage, but the thing is: How do i **compare test coverage** from previous run? 

In other words, i want to see incrementals of increased coverage in my project. I want to know for example a package has coverage of 40%, which is up from 38%.

Your suggestion is like i use IntelliJ today: It shows me the covered lines, and i manually see if a certain part of my code is covered after i added a test. This is powerful in itself, but i want more:)

Comment: I see, thanks for your feedback. Well, I usually see some red lines becoming green, therefore I understand they're covered :)