# How to make Intellij Idea Coverage display full colored lines?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

In Eclipse, most of the coverage plugins, display covered/partially covered/uncovered lines with different colors (i.e. **the whole line painted with a color**)

**In IntelliJ Idea, I couldn't find a way yet to paint the whole line with a descriptive color**, only a small, almost imperceptible mark is added on the left hand side, making the visualization of partially covered / uncovered lines really difficult.

Any idea?

Answer (score 87):

I found the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309677/intellij-show-changed-lines-not-covered-by-unit-tests) but I thought it would be better to create a specific, well-phrased question so that people having **exactly the same problem as me** can find it better in Google / StackOverflow.

In a nutshell, within `Editor -> Colors Scheme -> General --> Line Coverage`)

you can customize the Colors & Fonts used for covered/partially covered/uncovered lines, **modifying the background of the following entries**:

- Full
- Partial
- Uncovered

[image: Color configuration for Code Coverage in IntelliJ]

For example, I wanted to use the same default colors already provided but not only on the margin but on the whole line (similar to how Eclipse does it), so **I disabled "Foreground" and enabled "Background"**. Voilà!

[image: Whole lines painted in easy-to-view colors]

Comment: Thanks for this! I used to have my lines coloured until I switched to the Darcula theme, at which point it reverted to showing colours only in the margin. The solution is to create a new editable theme from the Darcula theme, and set your desired line styles (e.g. background colours) in that.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, setting either foreground or background still only results in a mark in the margin.

Comment: @AutomatedMike I had to close and reopen my tabs for the changes to take effect.

Comment: For me all the text disappeared. I had to restart to fix it.

Comment: Small hint, you also need to select the color you want for each of these entries, otherwise it defaults to grey, at least it did for me, so I just reset the theme to default values and just copied the existing red, green & yellow color hex codes for all three of the entries.

Answer (score 6):

I think the UI has been updated the the way to get to this option has changed. While it is already mentioned by others, I'd like to elaborate with a more detailed image to make it easier to see.

```
Intellij > Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Line Coverage >
```

There you will have three options.

- Full
- Partial
- Uncovered

Here is the menu option:
[image: Line Coverage Menu Option]

And here is what the question is specifically looking for:
[image: Line Coverage Background Coloring Menu Option]

Answer (score 2):

On the current apple version of IntelliJ you can find this under:

```
ItelliJIde > System Preferences > editor > Color Scheme > General
```

Then expand the arrow labeled
 `Line Coverage`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update I fixed by uncovered lines in Intellij attached the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: You need to expand on your solution a little. It's unclear what about this image is your solution. What lines in Intellij? What is the context?

Comment: I was not getting the highlighted color for the uncovered lines in junit. and i fixed it and attached the screenshot on how i did it....